# Any way to link to a specific Google Docs version (revision) using a shareable link?

Tags: google-docs

I know you can share a specific Google Doc with a shareable link, but is there a way to share a specific revision, or "named version" for viewing only?

I found this stackoverflow post from a few years ago showing how you can do it, but it no longer seems to work.

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/47662/how-can-i-link-to-revision-history-on-google-docs

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/100738/89937 works for me, as of today. Takes a bit of work. I submitted an edit to this answer (that clarifies a lot stuff), but that edit has not been published.  :-/

Comment: That particular answer is for Google Sheets, not Google Docs. Looks like there is no way to do what the OP is requesting within Google Docs today.